# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 66), found shape=(None, 67)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, algorithmic-trading

I get this error this error after few step of training of an RL script for trading

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1801, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1790, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1783, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1751, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 264, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 66), found shape=(None, 67)
```

The first part of code define an array from a pandas df of OHLC forex price:

```
        def _get_normalised_bars_array(bars):
            bars = bars.iloc[-10:, :-1].values.flatten()
            """Normalizing candlesticks"""
            bars = (bars-np.mean(bars))/np.std(bars)
            return bars

        self.state = np.append(self.state, _get_normalised_bars_array(self.last5m))
```

After that I create a pands df of features, I find the correlation and I create a df that I transform in np.array.flatten ana attache to the previous "self.state" array

```
correlation_ret = bars.corrwith(bars["returns_dir"]).sort_values(ascending=False)   
correlation_sel = correlation_ret.loc[(correlation_ret >= 0.55) & (correlation_ret < 1)].drop_duplicates(keep='last')   

df_correlation_sel = correlation_sel.to_frame().T  
columns = df_correlation_sel.columns.tolist()  
            
delete_element = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close']
for i in delete_element:
   if i in columns_def:
     columns_def.remove(i)
            
bars = bars[columns_def].iloc[-1:, :-3].to_numpy().flatten()
return bars

self.state = np.append(self.state, _get_tsfresh_features(self.last5m))
```

My DDQN network is the following:

```
def init_net(env, rl_config):
    """
    This initialises the RL run by
    creating two new predictive neural network
    Args:
        env:
    Returns:
        modelQ: the neural network
        modelR: the neural network

    """
    hidden_size = len(env.state)*rl_config['HIDDEN_MULT']
    modelQ = Sequential()
    modelQ.add(Dense(len(env.state), input_shape=(
        len(env.state),), activation=rl_config['ACTIVATION_FUN']))
    modelQ.add(Dense(hidden_size, activation=rl_config['ACTIVATION_FUN']))
    modelQ.add(Dense(rl_config['NUM_ACTIONS'], activation='softmax'))
    modelQ.compile(SGD(lr=rl_config['LEARNING_RATE']), loss=rl_config['LOSS_FUNCTION'])

    modelR = Sequential()
    modelR.add(Dense(len(env.state), input_shape=(
        len(env.state),), activation=rl_config['ACTIVATION_FUN']))
    modelR.add(Dense(hidden_size, activation=rl_config['ACTIVATION_FUN']))
    modelR.add(Dense(rl_config['NUM_ACTIONS'], activation='softmax'))
    modelR.compile(SGD(lr=rl_config['LEARNING_RATE']), loss=rl_config['LOSS_FUNCTION'])

    return modelQ, modelR
```

then I get the error exposed above with the following details:

[Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQPxC.png)

the Error doesn't appear if I exclude the "Technical Indicators" section.
How can I solve it? Is it due to the variable length of "Technical Indicators" array during the training?

Comment: Maybe your input shape doesn't match the actual input shape of your input data?

Comment: What do you mean by "variable length of "Technical indicators"? Your network is a simple MLP so it **requires** a fixed size input.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

After a few tests I've tried to lock the number of features and consequently the input shape. It works fine now, it seems that a variable number of inputs is not allowed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).